# JavaScript: string use in dynamic HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to JavaScript and have an issue with passing a string to 'innerHTML' as part of the dynamic creation of an HTML document. Reason for this: I need to specify an image path and want to be able to output a different image onto the screen depending on the details retrieved from a cookie (i.e. the image path changes each time so that image = 1001.jpg, image = 1002.jpg etc, depending on the object details retrieved). At present, unless I hardcode the line:

```
"<p><img src=\images/1005.jpg"\"</p>";
```

I don't get an output. I tried various ways of inputting a string into this line but no joy so far. My code is probably not the best, but it works, apart from the image issue:

```
function changeMe(){

 ...

 var studentObject = JSON.parse(getName); // info from cookie

 var path = studentObject.imagePath; // works: images/1005.jpg
 var res = path.charAt(10) 
 //alert(res); // = 5, works
 var newPath = "<p><img src=\"images/1001.jpg\"></p>";  
 // I 'amend' the newPath string value:
 **var answer = newPath.substr(0, 23) + res + newPath.substr(25.26);**
 //alert(answer); // works: <p><img src=\"images/1005.jpg"\</p>

 var oPara = document.createElement('p');
 oPara.style.fontFamily = "Arial sans-serif";
 oPara.style.fontSize = "20px";
 oPara.style.color = "#77787E";
 oPara.style.fontWeight = "bold";
 oPara.innerHTML = "<p><br>Name & Surname: " + studentObject.name + " " + 
 studentObject.surname + "</p>" + answer; // doesn't work
 //"<p><img src=\\" + "\"" + path + "\"" +"></p>"; // this doesn't work either

 document.body.appendChild(oPara);
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: remove everything from your code above that does not contribute to the problem.  eg 

oPara.style.fontFamily

This will get you better answers.

Comment: You made oPara as 'p' element. You can't nest p inside p.

Comment: BTW - it's ok to mix single and double quote in JS so you don't have to escape them: var newPath = "<p><img src='images/1001.jpg'></p>";

Answer (score 0):

Is this example helps?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title> Bla! </title>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function AddStudent() {
                var studentData = { "name":"John Dou" };  // for the exmaple.
                var paragraph = document.createElement('p');
                // set any style
                paragraph.innerHTML = "The student " + studentData.name + " added to the family";
                document.body.appendChild(paragraph);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick='AddStudent()'> Add Student </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications. I am still uncertain as to how I would add an image link to such a construct, and one where the image path is different each time, eg "<p><img src=\images/1005.jpg"\"</p>";

Comment: No worries. I found it!